# Get all elements with id above 4 (ID is combined by string and number )

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
  <div id="table1"></div>
  <div id="table2"></div>
  <div id="table3"></div>
  <div id="table4"></div>
  <div id="table5"></div>
  ...
```

How to select all elements with "table" and an ID > 4.

Comment: If it is quite simple why don't you try to do it? And when you get stack, then you can ask for help :)

Comment: Sorry, its not quite simple i guess.

Comment: Will the divs be ordered like they are in the example (starting from id table 1 and so on)? Or the id's will be mixed?

Comment: If they will be ordered like they will in the example, you can search for "table" and then retrieve the values indexed 5 and after in a for loop. Is there a solution for if they weren't ordered?

Answer (score 3):

Something like this might help you:

```
var test = /table(\d+)/;
$("[id^='table']").filter(function () {
  return parseInt(test.exec(this.id)[1], 10) > 4;
});
```

It will match all elements starting with `'table'` and then filter out those ending with values smaller than or equal to `4`.

Answer (score 1):

You can go over each element that the id starts with table [id^='table'] and check if the rest (the number) is bigger than 4

Example here http://jsfiddle.net/fLg00oxq/2/

```
$("[id^='table']").each(function(){
    var id = $(this).attr('id').substr(5);   // remove table and leave just the number
    if(id > 4 ){
        // Your code here
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Edit, Updated

Try

v1 (for numerically ordered `id`'s , i.e.g., `table1` -> `table2`)

```
$("[id=table4] ~ [id*=table]")
```

v2 (unordered `id`'s)

```
$("[id*=table]").not(function() {
  // return elements that _don't_ match the selector ,
  // `id` cast as `Number` <= 4
  return this.id.match(/\d+/)[0] <= 4
})
```

See

[Attribute Equals Selector [name="value"]](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-equals-selector/)

[Next Siblings Selector (“prev ~ siblings”)](http://api.jquery.com/next-siblings-selector/)

[Attribute Contains Selector [name*="value"]](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-contains-selector/)

[.not()](http://api.jquery.com)

```js
$("[id*=table]").not(function() {
  // return elements that _don't_ match the selector ,
  // `id` cast as `Number` <= 4
  return this.id.match(/\d+/)[0] <= 4
})
.each(function() {
  this.innerText = this.id
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <div id="table10"></div>
  <div id="table2"></div>
  <div id="table9"></div>
  <span></span>
  <div id="table6"></div>
  <div id="table5"></div>
  <div id="table1"></div>
  <div id="table7"></div>
  <div id="table8"></div>
  <div></div><br />
  <div id="table3"></div>
  <div id="table4"></div>
```

Comment: +1 for the simplicity! While this might work in the exact OP's case, just as a sidenote this might fail if - 1: #table4 is casually not present; 2: if tables are not siblings.

Answer (score 0):

This will do it:

```
$("div[id^=table]").slice(4);
```

Basically it selects all the div elements with id starting with "table". After that it removes four first matches and returns all the remaining jQuery objects.

So this has an assumption that there is `<div id="table1"> ... <div id="table2"> ... <div id="table[n+1]">`.

Comment: Oh, true. I assumed (according to the HTML in original question) that there's a list of div elements with id's "table1", "table2" and so on.

This returns all the div elements after fourth matched element.

Comment: I think you should provide enough explanation to your answer to help others understand.

Answer (score 0):

If your div they ordered will in example:

Edit your HTML :

```
<div class="table"></div>
<div class="table"></div>
<div class="table"></div>
<div class="table"></div>
<div class="table"></div>
```

Scripts

```
$(document).ready(function() {
 $('.table:gt(2)').each(function() {
    // Apply your functions for each div ....
 });
}
```

Comment: Where is id in div elements?

Comment: Why the `each` function? `$('.table:gt(2)')` returns already a collection.

Comment: While your suggestion to use a generic class if fine, sometimes is handy to know the exact ID of a targeted element...

Comment: Sorry, you're right. But i write this for example each or other method they allowed indeed .  My mistake.

Answer (score 0):

**[demo](http://jsbin.com/sejeva/1/edit)**

```
var $tables = $('[id^=table]').filter(function(){
  return +this.id.replace(/\D+/,'') > 4;
});
```

```
$tables.hide(); // Use example
```

the above will get the number out of the selector ID and compare if greater than 4. `$tables` will now result in a collection of elements returned by the jQuery's `filter()` method.

`.replace(/\D+/,'')` will remove all non-numeric (`D+`) Characters; the unary `+` will convert the String result to Number and `> 4` does the desired.

---

For a micro-Plugin extension you can go for:

```
// Retrieve elements from mixed ID str+number
// Returns a collection of elements with ID number greather than the num argument
$.fn.idNumGreaterThan = function(num){
  return this.filter(function() {
     return +this.id.replace(/\D+/,'') > num;
  });
};
```

```
$('[id^=table]').idNumGreaterThan(4).hide();
// Also with class selectors (element must have a mixed alphaNumeric ID)
$('.element').idNumGreaterThan(4).hide();
```

Answer (score -1):

You can try with this code, however i think that there are better ways to do it:

```
for (var i = 4; i <= 100; i++) {
    $('#table'+i)...
};
```

Comment: it should be `for (var i = 4; i <= 100; i++) {`

Answer (score -1):

You Could try the contain selector like so `$('div[id~=table]')`

Reference http://api.jquery.com/attribute-contains-word-selector/

Comment: Have you read the question? `Get all elements with id above 4`